# I have numbers in a string. how to put the numbers to a hashmap?

Tags: java, string, hashmap

In this code, im trying to make an implementation code of kruskal algorithm code with hashmap.so at the first code i save the code into a string then the value of the string need to be input into the hashmap.

```
private static final String FILENAME = "D:\\Kuliah\\Semester 7\\~USUL BULAN JANUARI\\PROBLEM\\sepuluh\\1.dat";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

                String content = "";

        BufferedReader br = null;
        FileReader fr = null;

        try {

            fr = new FileReader(FILENAME);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String sCurrentLine;

            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            content = content + sCurrentLine + "\n";
    //          System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {

            try {

                if (br != null)
                    br.close();

                if (fr != null)
                    fr.close();

            } catch (IOException ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

             System.out.print(content);

    }
         public static String extractNode(String content){
            String[] lines = content.split("\n");
            HashMap<Integer, Node> vertexs = new HashMap<Integer, Node>();

            for(int i=0;i<lines.length;i++){
             Node node = new Node();
             node.setId(0);
             vertexs.put(0, node);

                 //at this code how can i put it?

            }





            return "";
        }




}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching "java String to integer"?

Comment: is it necessary? because i think the value of the string can input to hashmap directly. in my hashmap there is no needed integer value but the ID it is.

Comment: You have `HashMap<Integer, Node>`, so yes, it is necessary to follow those object types. If you want the hashmap to hold a string, then make a `HashMap<String, Node>`

Answer (score 0):

For example you could do implement this:

```
String x = "5";
int num = Integer.parseInt(x); //coverts String to Integer
```

Hope this helps!

`

Comment: i think the value of the string can input to hashmap directly although the value in the string is integer. but in my hashmap integer is just for the uniqe number not the value.